# Loading 3D model moveit issue

Tags: urdf, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there !

I did an URDF for a robot in Computer-1 and it worked fine:

[image: image description]

but when I moved to Computer-2 I can't load my URDF in it and this is what i get:

[image: image description]

and this is what I get in the shell using my own package:

[image: image description]
[Click me](https://i.imgur.com/Z09u7hA.png) to extend

and this is what I get in the shell using staubli_rx160_support package:

[image: image description]

[Click me](https://i.imgur.com/JdwEhso.png) to extend

More info:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit, ROS Hydro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203995/loading-3d-model-moveit-issue/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2015-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-01**:
Please add more information: Linux distribution, version of distribution, ROS version, installed from source or binaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved:

in Moveit official [website](http://moveit.ros.org/install/) is written:

Note for Ubuntu 13.4 32 bit users: There is a bug with GCC 4.7 on Ubuntu 13.4 32bit with Eigen 3.1.2. It’s not likely to be fixed, so upgrade/downgrade your system to 13.4 64 bit resp. 12.4.

So don't use 32 bit distributions.

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-02**:\

> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit, ROS Hydro

the note you copied should apply only to ubuntu 13.04 users, which you seem not to be. I'm running a 12.04 32bit installation with MoveIt (from source and installed using `apt-get`) and don't experience any issues.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-02**:
I though that there is an issue with 32 bit either for Ubuntu 13 or 12, I don't know why you don't have the same problem. Now I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and it woks fine

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> [ WARN] [1425218598.009362723]: Assimp reports no scene in file:///home/jros/Downloads/staubli-hydro-devel/staubli_rx160_support/meshes/rx160/collision/base_link.stl
> ...
> ```

The quoted warning should give you enough information: the `assimp` library (used for loading mesh resources in many parts of ROS), cannot deal with the `stl` files that you (through the MoveIt Setup Assistant) are requesting it to load.

This could be a known issue with `assimp`. See [planning_component_visualizer bug](http://answers.ros.org/question/11569/planning_component_visualizer-bug/) and [ros-pkg/ticket/4740](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4740) (on the old ROS trac). In short: replace string `solid` at the start of your `stl` with something else.

Why this didn't happen on 'Computer 1', I cannot say.

PS: It would seem that these are actually not the meshes that are distributed in the [staubli_rx160_support](http://wiki.ros.org/staubli_rx160_support) package from ROS-Industrial, as those do not suffer from the issue described. I'm also pretty sure that the meshes shown in your first screenshot are in fact **not** from an RX160. I would advise you to create your own package, which reflects the actual model you have. This would also avoid potential name-clashes with the 'real' RX160 support pkg.

---

Edit:

> and this is what I get in the shell using staubli_rx160_support package:

How did you download those files? Could you check the first few bytes of `base_link.stl` for instance?

---

Edit2: ok, then this could be an OpenGL / video card driver issue. Make sure you have the correct -- and up-to-date -- drivers for your video card installed.

At the point where the Setup Assistant is loading the urdf, it starts to make proper use of your OpenGL subsystem. If anything is not ok there, it might lead to crashes such as your seeing. This is especially true if you are running Ubuntu/ROS in a VM.

In any case, make sure you have the correct (and up-to-date) drivers installed (check output of `glxinfo`, look at `OpenGL vendor/renderer/version` strings).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-03-01**:
In fact I have done my own package for TX60 and it works fine in Computer-1
PS: in both computers installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
It seem that Moveit is not well installed because I tested two packages (my own and staubli_rx160_support) that I know they work
I just edit my question to the new erro